# CHKDSK - Drive unusable after the scan

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, data-recovery, chkdsk

Drive is unusable after the CHKDSK scan. Any idea how I can fix this? It shows that the device is a raw device. I want to recover data and then format the drive.

```
File record segment 1432 is unreadable.
File record segment 1434 is unreadable.
File record segment 1439 is unreadable.
File record segment 143B is unreadable.
File record segment 1440 is unreadable.
File record segment 1443 is unreadable.
File record segment 144D is unreadable.
File record segment 1460 is unreadable.
File record segment 1462 is unreadable.
File record segment 1464 is unreadable.
An unspecified error occurred (696e647863686b2e 70c).
An unspecified error occurred (6e74667363686b2e 17b4).

C:\WINDOWS\system32>chkdsk /f g:
The type of the file system is RAW.
CHKDSK is not available for RAW drives.
```

[image: Screenshot of Crystal Disk Info]

[image: Screenshot of Disk Management]

Update: Disk is now showing as unallocated.
[image: Screenshot of Disk Management]

Comment: what type of disk is `f:`?

Comment: g: is the drive and its a 1TB seagate hdd.

Comment: sorry, yeah, g: (typo on my part) ... so it's a "1TB Hdd" ... I think that narrows it down to about 100,000 products - have you looked at "Disk Management" in windows?

Comment: Can you provide more details? Brand, model and type of the disk drive. Partition table and type.

Comment: The drive is dead. Buy a new drive and restore from backup.

Comment: You will probably need to recover the data using some sort of a third party software. Raw drive means:
*The file system of the drive is missing or damaged
*The RAW drive has not been formatted with a file system
*The current file system of the storage medium is not recognized by the computer

Comment: Is there any tool that can be used to recover filesystem? It was working fine before chkdsk. After chkdsk it started showing up as RAW device.

Comment: "g: is the drive and its a 1TB seagate hdd." Your picture above shows a disk from Western Digital. Data recovery requires more precision in description.

Comment: If your disk was working fine why did you invoke chkdsk?

Comment: Your disk was probably far from fine before you ran chkdsk, you just did not know it yet.

Answer (score 3):

Duplicate your dying disk using ddrescue to create a disk that has no physical sector errors. There is little chance that your broken sectors can be read but dealing with that duplicate that only has logical errors makes recovery attempts much easier. Run ddrescue using the mapfile parameter because that enables you to interrupt and continue your rescue session later if necessary.
If ddrescue has finished (what could take days or even weeks), save a screenshot or save the terminal window output because it gives you a quick overview of the state of your disk.

Then duplicate the duplicate which will run at the drive's sustained speed.

You can play around with your second duplicate.
Do not rely on being able to copy your failing source disk again. During a future copy operation there could be much more pending sectors showing up.

Consider paying a professional lab if the data is too important and you are not familiar with this type of operations.

Comment: Can you share the ddrescue command with mapfile?  I'm not sure how to use the mapfile.

Comment: also will I be able to mount the image just like ISO file and view all data without partition?

Comment: @Syedayaz The filesystem is already corrupted, making a copy won't improve things - it will just make sure that they don't get worse.

Comment: syed, read the manual, for examples, see chapter four:
https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html
When the source (hard drive) cannot be mounted, you obviously cannot mount the target (your copy) either. The copy is just the beginning of a recovery journey.

Comment: Thank you for ignoring my advice. dd is not the right tool. There is an article about data recovery on superuser.

Comment: This does not solve the problem of rescuing data.

Comment: pbies, this article is titled about a problem with chkdsk. What the user really wants is data recovery. If he correctly expresses his intents, his request would have been closed as a duplicate as there is an article about data recovery already. Avoiding degrading readibility is the most urgent issue now which is a crucial part of data recovery. 
You are invited to find and read the article about data recovery as well as syed.

Comment: @r2d3 Still the answer does not answer the question about data rescue. You only written "You can play around with your second duplicate", that is not enough.

Comment: 1) Create a duplicate copy using dd. 2) Restore the duplicate copy onto to new drive using dd. 3) Try data recovery on the new drive. But we can't mount it, maybe its because the partition is lost.

Comment: There was only 2 partition. I can recreate the partition.

Answer (score -5):

Drive soon will fail. You need another good drive, maybe two.

If you have possibility, make 2 copies of that whole drive on other media before messing around with `testdisk` on second copy.

To restore access to the drive, you should use `testdisk` from Linux distribution. Live USB should be enough. Write correct MBR to make the drive visible in Windows, files and folders will appear and then copy them to safe place.

Comment: There is no reason to apply Testdisk or any other software on a dying drive.

Comment: This is nonsense. "File record segment" refers to MFT file records, TestDisk can't help with this and also, you do NOT want to write to a drive in this state anyway.

Comment: @r2d3 To restore access to data he need to make the data readable by testdisk. Drive dying is another issue.

Comment: Pbies, you do not get the point how to treat a dying drive. Both quick search and deep search functions in Testdisk will stress a dammaged drive. If you read sectors anyway (running the functions mentioned above in Testdisk) you are better of saving them to a duplicate.